# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension , ipython 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython

I am new to ipython. I have this snippet of code in my ipython

```
def derivative(x):
    return 3*(x^2)
derivative_estimate = lambda x: difference_quotient(cube, x, h=0.00001)

x = range(-10, 10)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title("Actual Derivatives vs Estimates")
x = range(-10,10)
plt.plot(x, map(derivative, x), 'rx', label = 'Actual')           # red  x
plt.plot(x, map(derivative_estimate, x), 'b+', label = 'Estimate')  # blue +
plt.show()
```

When I try to run this, it shows me these errors

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-211954bb4dc5> in <module>()
      6 plt.title("Actual Derivatives vs Estimates")
      7 x = range(-10,10)
----> 8 plt.plot(x, map(derivative, x), 'rx')           # red  x
      9 plt.plot(x, map(derivative_estimate, x), 'b+')  # blue +
     10 plt.show()

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3152         ax.hold(hold)
   3153     try:
-> 3154         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3155     finally:
   3156         ax.hold(washold)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1809                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1810                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1811             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1812         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1813         if pre_doc is None:

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1422             kwargs['color'] = c
   1423 
-> 1424         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
   1425             self.add_line(line)
   1426             lines.append(line)

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _grab_next_args(self, *args, **kwargs)
    384                 return
    385             if len(remaining) <= 3:
--> 386                 for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
    387                     yield seg
    388                 return

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    362             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    363 
--> 364         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    365 
    366         if self.command == 'plot':

C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    221         y = _check_1d(y)
    222         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 223             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
    224         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    225             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension,
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: FYI: In Python `^` is not exponentiation; it is the "bitwise exclusive or".   Use `x**2` for "x squared".

Comment: Yes, I later figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib's `plot` function can't handle the iterator returned by `map`.  Expand the iterator to a list before calling `plot`:

```
plt.plot(x, list(map(derivative, x)), 'rx', label = 'Actual')
```

Comment: Yes that is the answer. Well I was too busy to answer my own post. But you already have done that. So accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `numpy` and then use either `numpy.linspace` or `numpy.arange` instead of `range`.  I believe your problem is created inside your function `derivative`, where you take `3*x`.  If `x` is a list (which is returned from the standard `range`, `3*x` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]` if `x=[1, 2, 3, 4]`. What you want to get is `3*x = [3, 6, 9, 12]`, and this will be the case if you use `numpy.linspace` or `numpy.arange` instead.

Documentation links:  [numpy.arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)  and [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

Comment: No, it does not have anything to do with numpy

Comment: What is the length of your x-list and what is the length of the list returned from your function derivative? If I use `x = range(-10, 10)` I get `len(x) = 20`, and `len(derivative(x)) = 60`.